# How to change fontfamily of text variable that contains a textfied value Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="altext">
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    useInput.style.fontFamily='arial';
    document.getElementById('altext').innerHTML = userInput;
}


</script>

</div>
```

This isnt working. I want it so that the font will change to arial or to my desired font family ! Thanks alot!

Comment: did you call your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
    var altText = document.getElementById("altext");
    altText.innerHTML = userInput.value;
    userInput.style.fontFamily = "arial";
    altText.style.fontFamily = "arial";
}
```

The problem is that `document.getElementById("userInput").value` is a string, not an HTML element. Hence you can't set it's font family. Instead you need to set it on `document.getElementById("altext")` or `document.getElementById("userInput")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `font-family` like:

```
document.getElementById('altext').style.fontFamily = 'arial';
```

In your current code, you are attempting to access `.style.fontFamily` on the value of a text-input, which is nothing but a string.